# Android error message when I run a new project

Tags: android, eclipse

When I create a new project and run it I get an error message popup that says

> Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.

There is no problem with the code since it is a fresh project. I am new to Android and am working on Eclipse.
I do not know how I can solve this. Any help will be appreciated. I also tried to clean the project then recompile it but the error still recurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the windows menu, select show view, problems, it should take you to the problems view (it's usually at the bottom).  That should have any errors listed in it.

It's also worth checking to make sure you don't have any open source files from other projects and that all files for the project you're working on are saved, as sometimes this can confuse eclipse.